# Media query - how do i make a div display on max-width when it's not initially displayed

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries, zooming

I have this div named "container" that is supposed to be displayed when the max-width gets to 47em. This can be triggered through zooming in. It's initial display is none but in the media query i change it to display block. The problem is that even after zooming in enough to get the max-width to become 47em, it's still not displaying anything. Why is this and how can i go about fixing the problem?

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWBJXv

```css
 html,
 body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 47em) {
   #container {
     display: block;
   }
 }
 
 div#container {
  display:none;
}
 
 div#nav {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   background: white;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #888888;
 }
 
 div#logo {
   border-right-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
   font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #1E3264;
   font-size: 2em;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="logo">TEST</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I misunderstood. Removing comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

First of all, `div#container` is a css selector with a **higher specificity** than `#container`, which you are using inside your media query, so the general rule takes precedence.

Second, make sure you always put your media-queried rules *after* your general rules.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvLLPa

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an order & specificity issue.

Try changing this

```
 @media (max-width: 47em) {
   #container {
     display: block;
   }
 }

 div#container {
  display:none;
}
```

to this:

```
 #container {
  display:none;
}

 @media (max-width: 47em) {
   #container {
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GpBByg)

Comment: Having an unmotivated day? I'm used to finding your answer explaining the problems and solution in detail :)

Comment: I was making the demo and posted then I saw you'd already made the point. So I left it and gave you the +1. :) ...and yes, I'm about out of close votes today...the dross is thick today.

Answer (score 0):

If you swap around your media query with your general css, and add an important tag this sorts out your issue example:

```
 #container {
  display:none;
}

 @media (max-width: 47em) {
   #container {
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/sshhdaniella/pen/EVppwR

Comment: Usage of `!important;` is almost *never* advisable, and in this case, also completely unnecessary. And even if using `!important;` would be the only solution here - it would make the switching unnecessary.

Comment: On second look, you are right, the use of important was unnecessary, using clear selectors and ordering is the issue here.